# Magnolia - limit i18n languages from code

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I'm working on a custom app for Magnolia and one of the requirements is to limit languages available for i18n (that dropdown) depending on the data from another app. So let's say that we have 4 languages available in my Magnolia: English, German, Spanish and Polish. In my app for some forms I want only to display English and Spanish but for others German, Spanish and Polish and this will depend on data from another app. Is there any way to do that?

I've read all documentation on i18n.